# Adding to Collection when Collection is Null

Tags: c#, generics, collections, ienumerable

I keep getting a null ref on the Children List when trying to add to the list via my property below

```
    public class Node<T> where T : INode
    {
        private readonly T _item;

        public IList<Node<T>> Children { get; set; } 

        public Node(T item)
        {
            _item = item;
            ParentNodeId = item.ParentNodeId;
        }


        public void AddChild(T childNode)
        {
            Children.Add(new Node<T>(childNode));
        }
....
```

And I wouldn't think you want to initiate the Children list every time it hits this property so what should I do to be able to add to this Node's children every time the calling code needs to populate it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try something like this may be

```
    public void AddChild(T childNode)
    {
        if(this.Children == null)
        {
           this.Children = new List<Node<T>>();
        }
        this.Children.Add(new Node<T>(childNode));
    }
```

Comment: don't need the this keyword.  You use R# :).  Might wanna..sorry pet peeve of mine, unnecessary code.  just an FYI.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: the this keyword is more of a "Standard" code for me, I have a compulsion to write code like that :)

Answer (score 2):

Add a default constructor.

```
public Node()
{
    Children = new List<Node<T>>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem adding a initializer in your constructor:

```
public Node(T item)
{
    _item = item;
    ParentNodeId = item.ParentNodeId;
    Children = new List<T>();
}
```

Or, if you really want it to be lazy-loaded, in the `add` method:

```
public void AddChild(T childNode)
{
    Children = Children ?? new List<T>();
    Children.Add(new Node<T>(childNode));
}
```

Comment: the problem I see is if that node does not have children, then I've created an empty object for nothing and that's costly...

Comment: @CoffeAddict, in the second option I gave, the collection is created only once you add the childNode

Answer (score 1):

Others have provided good answers, but I wanted to point out that noone has given the best way to do lazy initialization:

```
public class Node<T> where T : INode
{
    private readonly T _item;
    private readonly Lazy<List<Node<T>>> _children = new Lazy<List<Node<T>>>(
        () => new List<Node<T>>());

    public IList<Node<T>> Children { get { return _children.Value; } }

    public Node(T item)
    {
        _item = item;
        ParentNodeId = item.ParentNodeId;
    }


    public void AddChild(T childNode)
    {
        Children.Add(new Node<T>(childNode));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options: initialize the collection in the constructor or lazily in the AddChild.
But basically it's better to have not-null collections like this Children as it is public.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different usage scenarios, depending upon whether the `Children` property is supposed to return a persistent snapshot of the data, a live view of it, or a temporary read-only view that will be expressly invalidated if the data is modified, or a temporary read-only view whose behavior will be unspecified if the data is modified.

A key rule I'd recommend following when using mutable objects [such as `List<T>`] is that if a reference to an object might possibly get exposed to code which could mutate some aspect of its state, there should be at most one (generally exactly one) object in the system which considers the state of that object to be part of its own.  Neither .NET nor Java provides any convention to indicate whether an object holds a field for purpose of encapsulating mutable state held by its target; one must keep track of it manually.

Read-write properties of mutable types are only appropriate in cases where it's clear that the object which exposes the property has no ownership interest in the objects referred to thereby.  For example, a `List<Control>` encapsulates the *identities* of the `Control` objects whose references are contained therein; mutable aspects of those controls (e.g. their positions) do not constitute part of the state of the `List<Control>`.  Something like your `Node<T>`, however, would seem like it should own `Children`, since adding a child to `SomeNode.Children` would be considered a change to the state of `SomeNode`.  Consequently, the `Children` property should either be an immutable [not just read-only!] type (in which case ownership wouldn't matter) or else it should be a read-only property.  Otherwise, there would be no way to avoid murky semantics if code tries to set `Children` to a `List<T>` which is owned by some other object.

If `Children` is exposed as a read-only reference to a `List<T>` which is owned by the `Node<T>`, then a new `List<T>` must be created before the first attempt to read the `Children` property can return (it may be easiest to create the `List<T>` in the constructor for the `Node<T>`).  Another approach would be to define a private class `Node.ChildList` which holds a reference to a `Node<T>` and implements `IList<T>` and `ICollection` by accessing the internal fields of that node.  Using that approach, a `Node<T>` would have to create the lightweight `Node.ChildList` object even if no objects are ever added to it [it could be lazily created when `Children` are accessed, but it's probably better to create it in the constructor], but the `ChildList` implementation of things like `ICollection.Count` or `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()` could start by testing whether the node had created a collection yet and, if not, simply returning things suitable for an empty collection.

Incidentally, if `T` is a class type and many nodes would have exactly one child, it may be advantageous for `Node<T>` to store a `Count`, and an `Object`, rather than storing a `List<T>`.  If a node has no children, the `Object[]` would hold `null`; for one child, it would hold a `T`; for more children, either a `T[]` or a `List<T>`.  This would require more complex type-checking logic when accessing a node's children, but for nodes with zero or one children it would eliminate some heap allocations.